# Can Lucene's TermRangeQuery use a different sort order?

Tags: search, lucene

Lucene's [`TermRangeQuery`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/TermRangeQuery.html) sorts terms according to `BytesRef.compareTo`. There also exists `BytesRef.getUTF8SortedAsUnicodeComparator`, but there seems to be no way to use it for a `TermRangeQuery`.

In fact I would like to make the sort order more "natural" by sorting 'ä' right after 'a' or even treat them as identical. Looking at the code of `TermRangeQuery`, I end up in the `Automaton` class and wonder whether I would have to write my own automaton. Or is there an API available I am missing?

Comment: One thought: Would indexing these characters as their ASCII equivalents (ie. adding an [ASCIIFoldingFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_4_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/ASCIIFoldingFilter.html) to your analyzer) be a reasonable solution for you?

Comment: That is roughly what I am doing right now: recoding the strings such that I know what will happen exactly. But I have to work with strings that will not necessarily have ascii equivalents, I need to somehow cover the whole unicode range. I was just wondering whether instead of recoding a more direct way with a custom comparator is feasible.